# Wget gives Error 403: forbidden

Tags: .htaccess, httprequest, wget, http-status-code-403, httpforbiddenhandler

http://filedownloads.co.in/downloads/domain/October
In the above given web directory there are approx 30 zip file like

http://filedownloads.co.in/downloads/domain/October/2017-10-09hhwerahhqw_country-specific-database.zip
or
http://filedownloads.co.in/downloads/domain/October/2017-10-20weroiunewd_country-specific-database.zip

I want to download all file of that directory. I have tried all options available on stack-overflow related to my questions but every time i get the same Error 403: forbidden.
I have tried the following commands :
wget --user-agent="Mozilla" -r -np -A.zip http://filedownloads.co.in/downloads/domain/October
and
wget -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.zip -erobots=off http://filedownloads.co.in/downloads/domain/October/
and
wget -U firefox -r -np http://filedownloads.co.in/downloads/domain/October/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to visit your link using browser and received the same "Forbidden" message.

Try to open the link in Private window and see what happens.
It's quite possible that you are logged in on this site, so your browser has cookies which allow you to view this directory.
If so, you will need to find out these cookies and specify them too in wget so it can access the protected resource.

Comment: I'm also unable to access the top link, but the child links are accessible. There are no any cookies associated with the domain. There are approx 30 files in this directory and all are accessible with its complete link.

Comment: Well... If you haven't the file list accessible on the page, there is no way wget or curl or any other tool can determine file names and download the files.

Comment: If you have a list of files you want to download, then you can store it in a text file and then ask wget to download all files from that list.

If you only know some of file names and want to download another - then whooops, it's not possible.

To do so, you either need to guess the file naming algorithm or peform a brute force name guessing, which is very complicated.

Comment: will u help me to geues file name. The file names (2017-10-13hsjewewer_country-specific-database.zip) are based on this pattern. Date<>8 to 10 char alphabetical string<>_country-specific-database.zip

Comment: It looks like these letter prefixes are generated randomly. I'm afraid I can't help with it.